# Weird display of Select button in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

So this is happening to a select box I have:

[image]
[image]

Notice no scrollbar, and it's opening up all the way to the window title in IE8. This does not occur on Webkit or FF.

HTML:

```
     <div class="fblock">
            <label>Municipios</label><br />
            <select name="municipality" id="municipality" class="selector">
                <!-- todo: fill with municipalities-->

                    <option value="Aguada">Aguada</option>

                    <option value="Aguas Buenas">Aguas Buenas</option>

                    <option value="Arecibo">Arecibo</option>

                    <option value="Bayamón">Bayamón</option>

                    <option value="Cabo Rojo">Cabo Rojo</option>

                    <option value="Caguas">Caguas</option>

                    <option value="Canóvanas">Canóvanas</option>

                    <option value="Carolina">Carolina</option>

                    <option value="Cayey">Cayey</option>

                    <option value="Cidra">Cidra</option>

                    <option value="Dorado">Dorado</option>

                    <option value="Fajardo">Fajardo</option>

                    <option value="Guayama">Guayama</option>

                    <option value="Guaynabo">Guaynabo</option>

                    <option value="Gurabo">Gurabo</option>

                    <option value="Hatillo">Hatillo</option>

                    <option value="Humacao">Humacao</option>

                    <option value="Manatí">Manatí</option>

                    <option value="Mayagüez">Mayagüez</option>

                    <option value="Ponce">Ponce</option>

                    <option value="San Juan - Condado">San Juan - Condado</option>

                    <option value="San Juan - Hato Rey">San Juan - Hato Rey</option>

                    <option value="San Juan - Río Piedras">San Juan - Río Piedras</option>

                    <option value="San Juan - Santurce">San Juan - Santurce</option>

                    <option value="San Juan - Viejo San Juan">San Juan - Viejo San Juan</option>

                    <option value="San Sebastián">San Sebastián</option>

                    <option value="Toa Alta">Toa Alta</option>

                    <option value="Trujillo Alto">Trujillo Alto</option>

                    <option value="Yauco">Yauco</option>

            </select>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
select.selector {padding:2px 5px;
    border:1px solid #56AB4E; -moz-border-radius:.2em; -webkit-border-radius:.2em; border-radius:.2em;}
select.selector:focus {
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #77BE5E; -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #77BE5E; -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #77BE5E;}
div.fblock {display:inline-block; float:left; padding:0px 10px 10px 0px}
div.fblock.button {margin-top:10px}
div.fblock-container {clear:both; float:none; display:block; width:100%}
```

Any idea on what's happening? I've seen a few examples that deal with trimming problems on IE7, but this clearly isn't the case. Also compatibility mode in IE8 does not fix it.

I'm sure it's some CSS property that I'm overlooking but I'm stumped.

Comment: I took the code you provided here and tried to replicate this in IE8, but I wasn't able to, everything looked ok. It wasn't going up above the address bar. It might be something else in your code causing it:

http://i.imgur.com/IEpqYCN.png

This is a js fiddle of the code I used, though jsfiddle doesn't really work in ie8 http://jsfiddle.net/shayl/msgP9/

Comment: This is an indirect solution, but you could always implement [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). These are Javascript based replacements for the default `SELECT` elements. They should bring back the scrollbar, but at the cost of an extra script running on page load. However, both libraries also provide search functionality (type a few characters to filter the results), which is nice for a long list like yours.

Comment: If I had to guess at a cause, it's probably the `div.fblock { display: inline-block; }` triggering `hasLayout`. Try removing the `display: inline-block;` there (you don't need it if you're also floating the element).

Comment: @thirdender I removed the fblock to test for its css interfering, but the behavior still occurs.

Comment: @StaceyGarrison I guess I'll keep looking. It has to be an inherited CSS or something like that. Though looking at the firebug-like thing they have it only inherits font styles. Most of the css should be on its own class selector.

Comment: So apparently there's no solution for the whole sizing thing (i.e having it add a scrollbar). Apparently the sizes vary from browser to browser. I've googled my eyes out for days. I've decided to leave it as is. However I did find something weird regarding why it opens upwards. If I scroll down in IE, the dropdown drops down even though it still does not display a scrollbar. No idea what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `css`, maybe will help to solve the problem:

```
.selector{
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: I though it should. Thy to use this only for the .select. Just for now comment out other .selects'

Comment: Those two are the only selects in the css, i commented the focus one but it still doesn't work.